# page loads very slowly using tmdb api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

so i am trying to get trending movies and tv shows using tmdb api then i try to get the imdb id of them but the page render in a couple of second which is too slow i want to know if there is a way to optimize my code or if the problem is in the api calls

```
router.get('/',redirect,(req,res)=>{
    const option={
        url:"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=9bde952e56ff27d1016ff6144cbf27c9",
        json:true
    };
    const optiontv={
        url:"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/tv/week?api_key=9bde952e56ff27d1016ff6144cbf27c9",
        json:true
    }
    request(option).then(resp=>{
        let trending_id=[];
        trending_id=resp.results.map((movie)=>{
            const optionid={
                url:`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movie.id}/external_ids?api_key=9bde952e56ff27d1016ff6144cbf27c9`,
                json:true
            }
            return request(optionid).then(respid=>{
                return {id:respid.imdb_id,poster:`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2${movie.poster_path}`};
            }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
        })
        request(optiontv).then(resptv=>{
            let trending_id_tv=[];
            trending_id_tv=resptv.results.map((tv)=>{
                const optionid_tv={
                    url:`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${tv.id}/external_ids?api_key=9bde952e56ff27d1016ff6144cbf27c9&language=en-US`,
                    json:true
                }
                return request(optionid_tv).then(respid_tv=>{
                    return {id:respid_tv.imdb_id,poster:`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2${tv.poster_path}`};
                })
            });
            Promise.all(trending_id).then((values_movie)=>{
                Promise.all(trending_id_tv).then(values=>{
                    const user=req.session.name.split(' ')[0];
                    res.render('homepage',{name:user,imdbid_poster:values_movie,imdb_poster_tv:values});
                }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
            }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
        }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
    });
});
```

it takes sometimes up to 5 seconds to render the page

```
GET /home 304 5820.419 ms - -
GET /public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css 304 4.617 ms - -
GET /public/stylesheets/mdb.min.css 304 4.719 ms - -
GET /public/stylesheets/header.css 304 4.955 ms - -
GET /public/stylesheets/footer.css 304 4.406 ms - -
GET /public/stylesheets/flickity.css 304 5.950 ms - -
GET /public/stylesheets/homepage.css 304 5.407 ms - -
GET /public/javascripts/homepage.js 304 2.590 ms - -
GET /public/javascripts/header.js 304 5.542 ms - -
GET /public/javascripts/flickity.pkgd.min.js 304 3.179 ms - -
GET /public/images/logo.png 304 3.955 ms - -
GET /public/images/Recify%20background6.jpg 304 2.729 ms - -
GET /public/images/FavIcon.png 200 2.226 ms - 99291
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you instrumented your external requests. You can't make an external service respond quicker though.

What you can do is add some caching on your server.  Its unlikely that the data you are referencing changes very often. Even if you only cached for 15 minutes with your target of trending movies it would almost certainly help.

Comment: i am sorry i am a beginner can you simplify what i should do note:i am running the app on my localhost

Comment: Instead of always retrieving live data start storing the results into memory or into something like redis and check there first before making the request to imdb.